# Emit LiveData to update UI between subsequent suspend method calls

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to update the UI in between the suspend method calls when I get results from them. For example, here is my ViewModel class. Methods a(), b() and c() are suspend methods.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var userLiveData: LiveData<String>
    var repo = MainRepo()

     fun startTest() {
          userLiveData = liveData {
             var a =  repo.a()
             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@ $a")
             emit(a)
             var b = repo.b(a)
             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@ $b")
             emit(b)
             var c = repo.c(b)
             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@ $c")
             emit(c)
         }
    }
}
```

and this is my Activity class, where I am observing the LiveData

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.startTest()
        viewModel.userLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            text.text = it
        })
```

and Repo class

```
class MainRepo {

    suspend fun a(): String{
        delay(1000)
        return "A"
    }
    suspend fun b(a: String): String{
        delay(5000)
        return a + "B"
    }
    suspend fun c(b: String): String{
        return b + "-C"
    }
}
```

My Question is, how can I update the UI with results after I call `repo.a()` or `repo.b()` or `repo.c()`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with Mutable live data with coroutines. 
Also, a Suspend function can only be called by a coroutine or from another suspend function.
I have tested the below code. Hope this helps.

Your viewModel:

```
val userLiveData = MutableLiveData<Map<String, String>>()

fun startTest() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        var newVal = itemRepository.a()
        userLiveData.value = mapOf("responseTime" to newVal)
        newVal = itemRepository.b(newVal)
        userLiveData.value = mapOf("downloadSpeed" to newVal)
        newVal = itemRepository.c(newVal)
        userLiveData.value = mapOf("uploadSpeed" to newVal)
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
itemViewModel.userLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            result.get("responseTime")?.let {
                println("setting textField Response as :" +result["responseTime"])
            }
            result.get("downloadSpeed")?.let {
                println("setting textField2 Download Speed is :" +result["downloadSpeed"])
            }
            result.get("uploadSpeed")?.let {
                println("setting textField3 Upload Speed is :" +result["uploadSpeed"])
            }
        })
    itemViewModel.startTest()
```

Repo:

```
class MainRepo {

    suspend fun a(): String{
        delay(1000)
        return "A"
    }
    suspend fun b(a: String): String{
        delay(5000)
        return a + "B"
    }
    suspend fun c(b: String): String{
        return b + "-C"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
setting textField Response as :A
setting textField2 Download Speed is :AB
setting textField3 Upload Speed is :AB-C
```

Comment: This will update only one TextView everytime. I bwant to have 3 textviews and update them one by one. Take an example of speedtest, first method will update the ping duration, second method will update the download speed textview and third method will update the upload speed textview.

Comment: Okay. I have updated the answer. Tested it as well. Having a hashmap with different keys helps. Creating new map instances helps to avoid resetting the same field again. Also, to keep it simple you could use separate LiveData for each textField. But I personally prefer the above answer.

Comment: @Rookie Hi. Have you tried this yet? Do you think its the right answer?